# Knots: tighten rope used for fence

Tags: fence, rope-knots

I recently posted a similar question, but the design has changed, so here's the new question.

I have two 4-ft x 4" x 4" wood posts, and each post has two screw eyes. There's 12 feet of distance between each post. I would like to recreate the design in the image, but I want it to be tight, not sagging. I'd use a 3/4" rope with no stretch.

How can I tighten this rope so that it's taut? Once it's tight, I'd Like to use a knot to secure it (I'd rather use a knot than a crimp sleeve).

Since this more decorative, I can pull and then tighten, but I prefer using something that can make it even tighter.

[image]

Comment: I don't see how this is really a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Both the taut line or cinch would work I believe the cinch will get it tighter. Or a combination of cinch and a couple of 1/2 hitch to secure the cinch.

Comment: I would use a "trucker's knot"

Comment: @Briank the cinch is a truckers knot.

Answer (score 0):

Any kind of knot will be visible, so why not just use a cleat?  You can put it on the back of a fence post to minimize visibility.  It will make it really easy to adjust the rope if you ever need to, and makes it easy to tie it very tightly.

This answer will work whether you have just one fence panel or many.  Start by installing a cleat on the back of the post on one end of the fence.  Tie one end of the rope to the cleat, then feed the rope through the upper eye on that post.  Continue feeding it through all the upper eyes, going behind the posts (or through holes in the posts if you prefer) until you reach the other end.

[image: Fence with the upper rope only]

Now complete the end fence panel by running the rope diagonally, horizontally, and then diagonally again.  This will leave the end of the rope in position to to go behind (or through) the post to get to the next panel.  Continue until all panels are complete.  Then secure the end of the rope to the same cleat you used before.  (Or could be a different cleat if you prefer.)

[image: Completed fence]

Any time you want to tighten the rope (due to stretching or whatever), just untie one end from the cleat, pull it tight, wrap it around the cleat a few times so it won't slip, then tie it.